# How can I write Extension Functions in Kotlin?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

I just want to convert my normal function to extension function in Kotlin.

Here is my function,

```
fun hideKeyboard(activity: Activity) {
  if (activity != null) {
    activity.window?.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_SATE_HIDDEN)
    val view: View = activity.currentFocus
        if (true) run {
           val imm = activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
           imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.windowToken, 0)
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Are you trying to make this into an extension on `Activity`? What did you try so far?

Comment: `hideKeyboard(activity: Activity)` => `Activity.hideKeyboard()` and `activity` => `this` ?

Comment: @Selvin it could be an extension on `Activity?` as well so that the null check still makes sense

Comment: I didn't wrote a line in Kotlin :)

Answer (score 7):

You can even do that with an automatic refactoring provided by the IDE: place the cursor on the parameter that you want to convert to receiver, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> and select **Convert parameter to receiver**.

The result is:

```
fun Activity.hideKeyboard() {
    if (this != null) { // Note: this check is redundant, since the type is not-null
        window?.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_SATE_HIDDEN)
        val view: View = currentFocus
        if (true) run {
            val imm = getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.windowToken, 0)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `val view: View = currentFocus` could cause a NPE. It should be declared as nullable

Answer (score 3):

***How to create Extension Function*** (Object Class) :

```
object ViewExtension{

 fun CustomSpinner.validate(): Boolean  {
    if(!this.isSelected){
        this.setHintTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this.context,android.R.color.holo_red_light))
        this.setSpinnerHint(this.context.getString(R.string.please_select))
        return false
    }
    return true
 }

 fun TextInputLayout.validate(): Boolean{
    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(editText?.text)){
        this.error =  this.context.getString(R.string.required)
        return false
    }
    return true
 }
}
```

***How to use extension funtion***

```
fun validateFields(): Boolean{
    var allfieldsSelected = true

    textViewDetails.validate().apply {
        if(!this)
            allfieldsSelected = false
    }
    
    priority_spinner.validate().apply {
        if(!this)
            allfieldsSelected = false
    }

 }
```

Also another important part is we have import the validate method before we use it :

```
import com.example.activities.ViewExtension.validate
```

Answer (score -1):

**Let's take an example:**

***How to strike a text in textview with kotlin extension?***

Kotlin Extension

```
fun TextView.strikeTextView() {this.paintFlags = this.paintFlags or Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG }
```

Calling Extension

```
binding.tvText.strikeTextView()
```